# Rails: Omniauth & Devise. Getting a nil object unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, null

I followed Railscasts(ASCII versions) #235 and and part of #236 to setup creating user authentications using OmniAuth & Devise: [OmniAuth Part 1](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) [OmniAuth Part 2](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2)

I am at the stage where I just modified the `create` method of the `authentications controller` to allow user's not signed in to the site to sign in directly via twitter. The code for the `create` method is as follows:

```
  def create  
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]  
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])  
    if authentication  
     flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
     logger.info("AUTHENTICATION: #{authentication.inspect}")
     #logger.info("AUTHENTICATION METHODS: #{authentication.methods.sort}")
     logger.info("authentication.user: #{authentication.user}")
     #logger.info("authentication.user.nil?: #{authentication.user.nil?}")
     #logger.info("authentication.user.id: #{authentication.user.id}")  
     sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)  
    else  
     current_user.authentications.create(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])  
     flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."  
     redirect_to authentications_url  
    end  
  end
```

Now when I go to `/auth/twitter`, I get this error:

`No route matches "/auth/failure"`

This is because `authentication.user` is `nil`. The code for the `create` method is exactly as per the Railscast, and I don't see why `authentication.user` is nil.

This is the output of the `authentication.inspect`:

`#<Authentication id: 1, user_id: 1, provider: "twitter", uid: "319521616", created_at: "2011-08-01 10:32:48", updated_at: "2011-08-01 10:32:48">`

Does anyone have any insight as to why`authentication.user` would be `nil`, even tough the `inspect` method returns valid data.

Here is the code from my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :lockable, :confirmable #Added lockable and confirmable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any validations in your user model? This caused a silent fail on saving the user model, for me, which led to the error message you describe, when I did the same set up. Just one idea.

Comment: Using bang methods could reveal the silent failure.

Comment: Oh, yes that's how I solved my issue :-) ...I was just throwing it out there for the questioner - that the silent fail without the bang was the issue, and once I threw the bang in there I was able to identify it. I should have said - try adding the bang - cheers :-)

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work for me. I added bangs to `find_by_provider_and_uid!`, `sign_in_and_redirect!`, and `create!`. Still the same. 
I also tried removing the `:validatable` attribute from Devise in the User model, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: some other debugging questions on this - have you tried clearing all users and all authentications and starting with an empty database?  i had some issues with there being no user in the db matching an authentication which was still there... i.e. in your example above if there's no user with user.id == 1 in your db you'll fail ...and that can easily happen in dev. I suggest this because you're calling authentication.inspect after find_by_provider_and_uid before the create user step - which suggests an authentication is already there but perhaps the user got deleted during testing and tinkering

Comment: I've pasted it in my original post. Also, note that the ASCIIcast says that when a user who is not signed in tries to log in through twitter using the original code in the controller, I should be getting an error saying `undefined method 'authentications' for nil:NilCLass`, but the error I get is `No route matches "/auth/failure"` even in that case

Comment: i am saying something different - if you go to console and do User.first is there a user with User.id 1 to match the authentication above which thinks it belongs to a user.id 1?

Comment: @RichardJordan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2050/discussion-between-ankit-soni-and-richard-jordan)

Comment: hmm - i had this same issue just a few days ago - trying to remember what the root problem is ... will go tinker with the app i was working on at the time and see if i can tell from my comments